# Broadleaf template Location

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I Want to the Template Location of broadleaf site. for example the broadleaf site homepage is loaded from the layout/homepage  template and i want to know about the where other templates of broadleaf site are loading.

Please Help me to Solve the issue.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the Broadleaf templates are in the `templates` directory of the `site` project. There is a template resolver that specifically looks for this classpath location. Some of the templates are partials that are included as pieces of other templates with `th:include` and `th:replace`. Others are apart of larger layouts, as you found with `layout/homepage`.

However, URL resolution and template resolution are different things. For instance, the home page that you see is actually resolved by an entry in BLC_CATEGORY with a URL of `/`. This category also references the template path `layout/homepage`. The other form of dynamic URLs in Broadleaf are:

- Pages - entries in `BLC_PAGE`
- Products - entries in `BLC_PRODUCT`

all of which can load different Thymeleaf templates for display.

Comment: i found only home page template in the site templates and what about the other templates that are used in broadleaf site like hot-sauces and merchadise templates. and blc_page has only userdefined like aboutus like only